# High mass rigid body objects pass through

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have modeled a 2040 V slot and wanted to test out simulations for a bot that I am building. As a result, I had set the scene units to be scaled by 0.0001 since I need to model in millimeter(for 3D print purposes, used separately). I notice that when setting this as an active rigid body with any mass higher than ~2g it passes through the passive box rigid body below it. The same model with mass < 2g does not pass through. For realistic simulations, I need the mass of my object to be 245g and scale to be in millimeters.

I have tried increasing my rigid body iterations and steps as well. I have also tried changing it from kilograms to grams as well.

**Rigid body Settings**
[image: settings]

**Object rigid body settings**
[image: Object1]
[image: Object2]
[image: Floor]

**Final Simulation**
[image: Final simulation]

Comment: If you need realistic simulations, then you don't want to be using Blender.  Blender's physics are not real physics.

Comment: Got it. I thought I might as well try using the same software for modeling 3d print parts and for simulation. However even if the physics are not accurate, I don't think mass should be a factor for active bodies passing through passive bodies